K8 Permission issues in custom Scheduler
I'm encountering errors when deploying my custom scheduler following this link. I've identified them as permission issues, and despite updating my RBAC files, the errors persist.
"Plugin Failed" err="pods \"my-scheduler-5bdf8b8594-f8r9q\" is forbidden: User \"system:kube-scheduler\" cannot create resource \"pods/binding\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"" plugin="DefaultBinder" pod="kube-system/my-scheduler-5bdf8b8594-f8r9q" node="ubuntu22.04lts"

E0502 07:22:52.955623       1 schedule_one.go:989] "Error scheduling pod; retrying" err="running Bind plugin \"DefaultBinder\": pods \"my-scheduler-5bdf8b8594-f8r9q\" is forbidden: User \"system:kube-scheduler\" cannot create resource \"pods/binding\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"" pod="kube-system/my-scheduler-5bdf8b8594-f8r9q"

W0502 07:22:57.557777       1 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:kube-scheduler" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope

E0502 07:22:57.557810       1 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: services is forbidden: User "system:kube-scheduler" cannot list resource "services" in API group "" at the cluster scope

And this is the vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150
// WaitForCacheSync waits for all started informers' cache were synced.
func (f *sharedInformerFactory) WaitForCacheSync(stopCh <-chan struct{}) map[reflect.Type]bool {
    informers := func() map[reflect.Type]cache.SharedIndexInformer {
        f.lock.Lock()
        defer f.lock.Unlock()

        informers := map[reflect.Type]cache.SharedIndexInformer{}
        for informerType, informer := range f.informers {
            if f.startedInformers[informerType] {
                informers[informerType] = informer
            }
        }
        return informers
    }()

    res := map[reflect.Type]bool{}
    for informType, informer := range informers {
        res[informType] = cache.WaitForCacheSync(stopCh, informer.HasSynced)
    }
    return res
}

In the RBAC file, does anyone have insights into what additional updates are needed? Any suggestions would be appreciated.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler-as-kube-scheduler
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:kube-scheduler
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler-as-volume-scheduler
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:volume-scheduler
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: my-scheduler-extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: my-scheduler
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: system:kube-scheduler
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["create"]
  - apiGroups: ["coordination.k8s.io"]
    resourceNames: ["kube-scheduler", "my-scheduler"]
    resources: ["leases"]
    verbs: ["get", "update"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resourceNames: ["kube-scheduler", "my-scheduler"]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    verbs: ["delete", "get", "patch", "update"]
---

